# Android - Android Studio vs. Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have been more of a web developer than an application developer. Lately I've been thinking of making an Android App. The Internet is telling me that I can go two ways: Android Studio, or a third party program such as Eclipse, PhoneGap, Xamarin, or Apache Cordova. Being a web developer, I see HTML, CSS, and JS and know that I don't have to learn a new language to develop apps. My question is: which is better for app development? Apache Cordova or Android Studio. Which has a **better API**, **native feel**, **performance**, those sort of things. I have no experience with Java or C++, but lots of experience with web languages and C#. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Don't mix you apples and oranges. Android Studio is just an IDE, Cordova is a library and a framework for hybrid development. Decide if you want to write native or hybrid apps, and go from there. Google for hibrid vs native development to see what's what

Comment: Yes, just did, hybrid should be better personally, but what I hear is that hybrids are perform worse, and have less functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely native app development will give you the best performance. Hybrid apps are nothing but a html code loaded in a webview.  For a comparison open any jquery website in any browser and try its android app. It may be simple for you to develop hybrid app but native apps are totally worth it.
Happy coding:)

Comment: Thanks @nikka , I look forward to starting developing native!